# geting one by one char in jquery by Json

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have asp.net mvc 2 application.
 since couple of days I was trying to read the List from action of controller to Jquery by returning the Json through the action. but need lot of time and effort to resolve this.now i am able to read the json data by using :

```
$.getJSON('/LoadTest/GetAllQuestionsForTest', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        alert(item);
    });
});
```

since, my json output is :

```
[{"QuestionId":2,"QuestionText":"Question 1","TopicId":1},{"QuestionId":3,"QuestionText":"Question 2","TopicId":1}]
```

where as I am getting here one by one char in alert box rather than string like "QuestionId". I want to read the value of "QuestionId" and "QuestionText" from this script how can i do that ?
even i tried data["QuestionId"] but anable to read it

**Edited**

```
This is working for me :

      $.getJSON('/LoadTest/GetAllQuestionsForTest', function(data) {

                var t = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(t[0].QuestionText);


            });
```

but showing only 0'th indexed value. I want to get count of objects in data collection. so that i can iterate it. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
alert(data[0].QuestionId)
```

try to do:

```
$.get("/LoadTest/GetAllQuestionsForTest", function(data) {
   alert(data);
   var t = $.parseJSON(data);
   alert(t);
})
```

What the output ?

btw you using this on your controller? :

```
return Json(object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: But data is an an array of questions

Comment: this is also  
giving me undefined as alert

Comment: what do you get with just an alert(data) ?

Comment: giving me undefined on alert box

Comment: the first alert or the second one ?

Comment: I think either the problem is not as you have written it, or you're trying something completely different than these solutions.

Comment: no no, i am getting this as alert exactly. two times [object Object]

Comment: resolved for index issue :   count = t.length;  for (j = 1; j <= count; j++) {//code here}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
alert(data[i].QuestionId);
alert(data[i].QuestionText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

It looks like

```
$.each(data, function(i) {
    alert(data[i].QuestionId);
});
```

should do the trick?

Comment: this is also giving me undefined as alert

Comment: alex answer showing me [object Object],[object Object] can you explore it , what is it exactly

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
alert(item[i].QuestionId);
```

ok lets remove the each.

write

```
alert(data[0].QuestionId);
```

instead

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
        alert(item);
    });
```

Comment: No this is also giving undefined

Comment: @ enthusiastic: i had tried this earlier, but still i am unfortunate

Answer (score 0):

Function each in this case is grabbing each array.  You probably want to iterate the values of the arrays with an inner each.

```
$.each(json, function(i,item) {
    $.each(item, function(j,subitem) {
        alert(subitem);       
    });
});
```

Comment: so what you got there ? I am getting '[' '{' '"'... per alert box

Comment: ...  
Are you clicking on the link in my comment... or what?

Comment: sorry, but didn't get this output as we getting on link site